# Opt to generate assemblies alway as native image

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have few components in my project (C# and Managed C++ assemblies and applications). I would like to generate on assembly as native image always after building the project. Is there any project-settings to do that automatically without the help of NGen?

Comment: You could use a postbuild event to run ngen.exe on your .exe.  There's very little point to this, zero when you do this on the Debug build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be useless, as the NGen result is only usable on your machine. If this is a product that is going to be deployed to other machines, you are supposed to call NGen in the installer during post-installation phase,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6t9t5wcf(v=vs.80).aspx